# Can I go inside the airport in the UK to meet someone?

Tags: uk, airports, airport-security

My wife and child are arriving next week at Birmingham airport in the UK. They would have good amount of luggage. Is it possible that I could go inside airport at the luggage collection point to meet them?

Comment: Are they arriving on an international flight?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can enter the customs and immigration screening area?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite likely that you can get a *gate pass*.  This is like a boarding pass, but would allow you to go to their gate to meet them.  Note that this will only be an option if they are flying domestically.  If they are clearing customs and immigration in Birmingham, then you would likely not be allowed to go to them as you would have to clear customs yourself.

Speak to the airline that's flying your family as soon as possible and ask if you can get a gate pass at Birmingham airport.  Just explain that they could use the help dealing with their luggage.  If you qualify and your airline issues such passes at that airport, you'll pick up your gate pass at the check-in counter an hour or two before the flight arrives, just as if you were flying yourself.

Comment: They are flying in from other country, so i think i would have to wait outside

Comment: @MohitLeekha I suspect you're right.  Still, ask the airline.  You never know.

Comment: @MohitLeekha Just to be sure you understand, if they are flying from abroad but to another UK airport first (e.g. to London Heathrow) then connecting to Birmingham, they will be on a domestic flight.

Comment: UK airports do not have "gate passes"; you need a boarding pass or a CAA airside pass. The domestic bag claims are also segregated from the outside world. Very unlikely they are on a connecting flight to BHX via another UK airport, but it is narrowly possible; the only airline that could do this is Flybe, possibly from ABZ; BE charge steep interline fees.

Comment: @Calchas So what you're saying is, unless you are flying the same day or work at an airport, the answer is "no"?